# Word or phrase for waving your fists around without hitting the opponent

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a word or phrase for waving your fists around without hitting the opponent?

You just wave your fists around but can't hit the opponent missing almost every time. Or you fight with your hands like in the youTube video [Showdown - Simon's Cat (Jazz Trilogy! - 3/3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPg9iBVOIZE).

That's the closest I could find to ask what I mean.

Comment: Please read the description of the single-word-request tag. When asking this sort of question, you need to include an example sentence so we know what kind of thing you're after. That said, you're probably looking for _flailing_.

Comment: Click on the tag [tag:single-word-requests] in your question to see the policy. It's in capitals, even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A word that describes this type of "non-hitting" action is [**flail**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flail#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> transitive verb
>
> **1 a** : to strike with or as if with a flail • The bird's wings *flailed* the water.
> **b** : to move, swing, or beat as if wielding a flail • *flailing* a club to drive away the insects
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to move, swing, or beat like a flail • arms flailing in the water

[Oxford's definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flail) of the verb also makes it more specifically clear that this kind of action, when used to describe somebody swinging at somebody else, is mostly ineffectual:

> Wave or swing wildly.
>
> ‘Josh's arms flailed wildly, catching Katie in the face at times.’
> ‘She lashed out at him now, her arms and legs flailing wildly, her kicks and punches missing their target by a considerable margin.’

I find it a little odd that all of the Oxford examples use "flail wildly" when "wildly" is already part of the definition of the word. Personally, if I used the word, I wouldn't add that adjective to it.

Comment: Can I say flailing hands or fists?

Comment: @Dunno Yes, you can.